# Vulkan image layout not transitioning in pipeline barrier

Tags: c++, rust, vulkan

I ported most of [Introduction to Vulkan - Tutorial 02](https://github.com/GameTechDev/IntroductionToVulkan/blob/master/Project/Tutorial02/Tutorial02.cpp) from C++ into a single Rust function to keep it simple. The function calls Vulkan through Rust FFI provided by [ash](https://github.com/MaikKlein/ash).

I'm having an issue getting the pipeline barriers and semaphores to function correctly. As far as I can tell, this code seems to create the same validation debug log info as the C++ code.

When I run the C++ code with validation layers enabled, `vkQueueSubmit` is successful. When I run the Rust function below (with validation layers enabled), `queue_submit` fails and I receive

> Cannot submit cmd buffer using image (0x6) [sub-resource: aspectMask
>   0x1 array layer 0, mip level 0], with layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED
>   when first use is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL.

...which implies to me that there the image layout transition isn't taking place, so there may be something wrong with how I configure/submit my pipeline barriers.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate ash;
extern crate kernel32;
extern crate winit;
use std::default::Default;
use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};
use std::ptr;
use ash::vk;
use ash::Entry;
use ash::extensions::{DebugReport, Surface, Swapchain, Win32Surface};
use ash::version::{DeviceV1_0, EntryV1_0, InstanceV1_0};
use winit::os::windows::WindowExt;

unsafe extern "system" fn vulkan_debug_callback(
    _: vk::DebugReportFlagsEXT,
    _: vk::DebugReportObjectTypeEXT,
    _: vk::uint64_t,
    _: vk::size_t,
    _: vk::int32_t,
    _: *const vk::c_char,
    p_message: *const vk::c_char,
    _: *mut vk::c_void,
) -> u32 {
    println!("{:?}", CStr::from_ptr(p_message));
    1
}

fn main() {
    let mut events_loop = winit::EventsLoop::new();
    let window_width = 1024;
    let window_height = 768;
    let window = winit::WindowBuilder::new()
        .with_title("Example")
        .with_dimensions(window_width, window_height)
        .build(&events_loop)
        .unwrap();

    unsafe {
        let entry = Entry::new().unwrap();
        let name = CString::new("Example").unwrap();
        let name_raw = name.as_ptr();

        let app_info = [
            vk::ApplicationInfo {
                s_type: vk::StructureType::ApplicationInfo,
                p_next: ptr::null(),
                p_application_name: name_raw,
                application_version: 0,
                p_engine_name: name_raw,
                engine_version: 0,
                api_version: vk_make_version!(1, 0, 36),
            },
        ];

        let layer_names = [CString::new("VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation").unwrap()];
        let layer_names_raw: Vec<*const i8> = layer_names.iter().map(|x| x.as_ptr()).collect();

        let extension_names_raw = vec![
            Surface::name().as_ptr(),
            Win32Surface::name().as_ptr(),
            DebugReport::name().as_ptr(),
        ];

        let create_info = vk::InstanceCreateInfo {
            s_type: vk::StructureType::InstanceCreateInfo,
            p_next: ptr::null(),
            flags: Default::default(),
            p_application_info: app_info.as_ptr(),
            pp_enabled_layer_names: layer_names_raw.as_ptr(),
            enabled_layer_count: layer_names_raw.len() as u32,
            pp_enabled_extension_names: extension_names_raw.as_ptr(),
            enabled_extension_count: extension_names_raw.len() as u32,
        };

        let instance = entry.create_instance(&create_info, None).unwrap();

        let debug_info = vk::DebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT {
            s_type: vk::StructureType::DebugReportCallbackCreateInfoExt,
            p_next: ptr::null(),
            flags: vk::DEBUG_REPORT_ERROR_BIT_EXT | vk::DEBUG_REPORT_WARNING_BIT_EXT |
                vk::DEBUG_REPORT_PERFORMANCE_WARNING_BIT_EXT |
                vk::DEBUG_REPORT_INFORMATION_BIT_EXT |
                vk::DEBUG_REPORT_DEBUG_BIT_EXT,
            pfn_callback: vulkan_debug_callback,
            p_user_data: ptr::null_mut(),
        };

        let debug_report_loader = DebugReport::new(&entry, &instance).unwrap();

        let debug_callback = debug_report_loader
            .create_debug_report_callback_ext(&debug_info, None)
            .unwrap();

        let surface_loader = Surface::new(&entry, &instance).unwrap();
        let win32_create_info = vk::Win32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR {
            s_type: vk::StructureType::Win32SurfaceCreateInfoKhr,
            p_next: ptr::null(),
            flags: Default::default(),
            hinstance: kernel32::GetModuleHandleW(ptr::null()) as *mut _,
            hwnd: window.get_hwnd() as *mut _,
        };

        let surface = Win32Surface::new(&entry, &instance)
            .unwrap()
            .create_win32_surface_khr(&win32_create_info, None)
            .unwrap();

        let (physical_device, graphics_queue_family_index, present_queue_family_index) = instance
            .enumerate_physical_devices()
            .unwrap()
            .iter()
            .filter_map(|&p| {
                let candidates =
                    instance
                        .get_physical_device_queue_family_properties(p)
                        .iter()
                        .enumerate()
                        .filter_map(|(index, info)| {
                            let has_graphics = info.queue_flags.subset(vk::QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT);
                            let has_present = surface_loader
                                .get_physical_device_surface_support_khr(p, index as u32, surface);
                            if has_graphics || has_present {
                                Some((index as u32, has_graphics, has_present))
                            } else {
                                None
                            }
                        })
                        .collect::<Vec<(u32, bool, bool)>>();
                match candidates.iter().find(|&x| x.1 && x.2) {
                    Some(ref both) => Some((p, both.0, both.0)),
                    None => match candidates.iter().find(|&x| x.1) {
                        Some(ref graphics) => match candidates.iter().find(|&x| x.2) {
                            Some(ref present) => Some((p, graphics.0, present.0)),
                            None => None,
                        },
                        None => None,
                    },
                }
            })
            .nth(0)
            .unwrap();

        let device_extension_names_raw = [Swapchain::name().as_ptr()];
        let queue_priorities = [1.0];
        let queue_create_infos = [
            vk::DeviceQueueCreateInfo {
                s_type: vk::StructureType::DeviceQueueCreateInfo,
                p_next: ptr::null(),
                flags: Default::default(),
                queue_family_index: graphics_queue_family_index,
                p_queue_priorities: queue_priorities.as_ptr(),
                queue_count: queue_priorities.len() as u32,
            },
        ];

        let device_create_info = vk::DeviceCreateInfo {
            s_type: vk::StructureType::DeviceCreateInfo,
            p_next: ptr::null(),
            flags: Default::default(),
            queue_create_info_count: 1 as u32,
            p_queue_create_infos: queue_create_infos.as_ptr(),
            enabled_layer_count: 0,
            pp_enabled_layer_names: ptr::null(),
            enabled_extension_count: device_extension_names_raw.len() as u32,
            pp_enabled_extension_names: device_extension_names_raw.as_ptr(),
            p_enabled_features: ptr::null(),
        };
        let device = instance
            .create_device(physical_device, &device_create_info, None)
            .unwrap();

        let present_queue = device.get_device_queue(present_queue_family_index, 0);

        let image_available_semaphore_create_info = vk::SemaphoreCreateInfo {
            s_type: vk::StructureType::SemaphoreCreateInfo,
            p_next: ptr::null(),
            flags: Default::default(),
        };
        let image_available_semaphore = device
            .create_semaphore(&image_available_semaphore_create_info, None)
            .unwrap();

        let render_complete_semaphore_create_info = vk::SemaphoreCreateInfo {
            s_type: vk::StructureType::SemaphoreCreateInfo,
            p_next: ptr::null(),
            flags: Default::default(),
        };
        let render_complete_semaphore = device
            .create_semaphore(&render_complete_semaphore_create_info, None)
            .unwrap();
        let swapchain_loader = Swapchain::new(&instance, &device).unwrap();

        let pool_create_info = vk::CommandPoolCreateInfo {
            s_type: vk::StructureType::CommandPoolCreateInfo,
            p_next: ptr::null(),
            flags: vk::CommandPoolCreateFlags::empty(),
            queue_family_index: present_queue_family_index,
        };

        device.device_wait_idle().unwrap();
        let surface_capabilities = surface_loader
            .get_physical_device_surface_capabilities_khr(physical_device, surface)
            .unwrap();

        let surface_formats = surface_loader
            .get_physical_device_surface_formats_khr(physical_device, surface)
            .unwrap();

        let surface_format =
            if surface_formats.len() == 1 && surface_formats[0].format == vk::Format::Undefined {
                vk::SurfaceFormatKHR {
                    format: vk::Format::B8g8r8Unorm,
                    color_space: surface_formats[0].color_space,
                }
            } else {
                match (surface_formats)
                    .iter()
                    .find(|&sf| sf.format == vk::Format::B8g8r8Unorm)
                {
                    Some(sf) => sf.clone(),
                    None => surface_formats[0].clone(),
                }
            };

        let image_extent = match surface_capabilities.current_extent.width {
            std::u32::MAX => vk::Extent2D {
                width: window_width,
                height: window_height,
            },
            _ => surface_capabilities.current_extent.clone(),
        };

        let mut image_count = surface_capabilities.min_image_count + 1;
        if surface_capabilities.max_image_count > 0 &&
            image_count > surface_capabilities.max_image_count
        {
            image_count = surface_capabilities.max_image_count;
        }

        image_count = image_count;

        let pre_transform = if surface_capabilities
            .supported_transforms
            .subset(vk::SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR)
        {
            vk::SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR
        } else {
            surface_capabilities.current_transform
        };

        let present_modes = surface_loader
            .get_physical_device_surface_present_modes_khr(physical_device, surface)
            .unwrap();

        let present_mode = present_modes
            .iter()
            .cloned()
            .find(|&mode| mode == vk::PresentModeKHR::Fifo)
            .unwrap_or(vk::PresentModeKHR::Fifo);

        let swapchain_create_info = vk::SwapchainCreateInfoKHR {
            s_type: vk::StructureType::SwapchainCreateInfoKhr,
            p_next: ptr::null(),
            flags: Default::default(),
            surface: surface,
            min_image_count: image_count,
            image_color_space: surface_format.color_space,
            image_format: surface_format.format,
            image_extent: image_extent,
            image_usage: vk::IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT | vk::IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT,
            image_sharing_mode: vk::SharingMode::Exclusive,
            pre_transform,
            composite_alpha: vk::COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR,
            present_mode,
            clipped: 1,
            old_swapchain: vk::SwapchainKHR::null(),
            image_array_layers: 1,
            p_queue_family_indices: ptr::null(),
            queue_family_index_count: 0,
        };

        let swapchain = swapchain_loader
            .create_swapchain_khr(&swapchain_create_info, None)
            .unwrap();

        let command_pool = device.create_command_pool(&pool_create_info, None).unwrap();

        let command_buffer_allocate_info = vk::CommandBufferAllocateInfo {
            s_type: vk::StructureType::CommandBufferAllocateInfo,
            p_next: ptr::null(),
            command_buffer_count: image_count,
            command_pool: command_pool,
            level: vk::CommandBufferLevel::Primary,
        };

        let command_buffers = device
            .allocate_command_buffers(&command_buffer_allocate_info)
            .unwrap();

        let swapchain_images = swapchain_loader
            .get_swapchain_images_khr(swapchain)
            .unwrap();

        let command_buffer_begin_info = vk::CommandBufferBeginInfo {
            s_type: vk::StructureType::CommandBufferBeginInfo,
            p_next: ptr::null(),
            p_inheritance_info: ptr::null(),
            flags: vk::COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT,
        };

        let subresource_range = vk::ImageSubresourceRange {
            aspect_mask: vk::IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT,
            base_mip_level: 0,
            level_count: 1,
            base_array_layer: 0,
            layer_count: 1,
        };

        for (index, swapchain_image) in swapchain_images.iter().enumerate() {
            let barrier_from_present_to_clear = vk::ImageMemoryBarrier {
                s_type: vk::StructureType::ImageMemoryBarrier,
                p_next: ptr::null(),
                src_access_mask: vk::ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT,
                dst_access_mask: vk::ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT,
                old_layout: vk::ImageLayout::Undefined,
                new_layout: vk::ImageLayout::TransferDstOptimal,
                src_queue_family_index: vk::VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED,
                dst_queue_family_index: vk::VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED,
                image: *swapchain_image,
                subresource_range: subresource_range.clone(),
            };

            let barrier_from_clear_to_present = vk::ImageMemoryBarrier {
                s_type: vk::StructureType::ImageMemoryBarrier,
                p_next: ptr::null(),
                src_access_mask: vk::ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT,
                dst_access_mask: vk::ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT,
                old_layout: vk::ImageLayout::TransferDstOptimal,
                new_layout: vk::ImageLayout::PresentSrcKhr,
                src_queue_family_index: vk::VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED,
                dst_queue_family_index: vk::VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED,
                image: *swapchain_image,
                subresource_range: subresource_range.clone(),
            };

            let command_buffer = command_buffers[index];

            device
                .begin_command_buffer(command_buffer, &command_buffer_begin_info)
                .unwrap();

            device.cmd_pipeline_barrier(
                command_buffer,
                vk::PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                vk::PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                vk::DependencyFlags::empty(),
                &[],
                &[],
                &[barrier_from_present_to_clear],
            );

            let clear_color = vk::ClearColorValue::new_float32([1.0, index as f32 / 4.0, 0.2, 0.0]);

            device.cmd_clear_color_image(
                command_buffer,
                *swapchain_image,
                vk::ImageLayout::TransferDstOptimal,
                &clear_color,
                &[subresource_range.clone()],
            );

            device.cmd_pipeline_barrier(
                command_buffer,
                vk::PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                vk::PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT,
                vk::DependencyFlags::empty(),
                &[],
                &[],
                &[barrier_from_clear_to_present],
            );

            device.end_command_buffer(command_buffer).unwrap();
        }

        events_loop.run_forever(|event| match event {
            winit::Event::WindowEvent {
                event: winit::WindowEvent::Closed,
                ..
            } => {
                device.device_wait_idle().unwrap();
                device.destroy_semaphore(image_available_semaphore, None);
                device.destroy_semaphore(render_complete_semaphore, None);

                device.destroy_command_pool(command_pool, None);
                swapchain_loader.destroy_swapchain_khr(swapchain, None);
                device.destroy_device(None);
                surface_loader.destroy_surface_khr(surface, None);
                debug_report_loader.destroy_debug_report_callback_ext(debug_callback, None);
                instance.destroy_instance(None);
                winit::ControlFlow::Break
            }
            _ => {
                let image_index = swapchain_loader
                    .acquire_next_image_khr(
                        swapchain,
                        std::u64::MAX,
                        image_available_semaphore,
                        vk::Fence::null(),
                    )
                    .unwrap();

                let present_semaphores = [image_available_semaphore];
                let render_semaphores = [render_complete_semaphore];
                let command_buffer = [command_buffers[image_index as usize]];

                let submit_info = [
                    vk::SubmitInfo {
                        s_type: vk::StructureType::SubmitInfo,
                        p_next: ptr::null(),
                        wait_semaphore_count: present_semaphores.len() as u32,
                        p_wait_semaphores: present_semaphores.as_ptr(),
                        p_wait_dst_stage_mask: &vk::PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                        command_buffer_count: command_buffer.len() as u32,
                        p_command_buffers: command_buffer.as_ptr(),
                        signal_semaphore_count: render_semaphores.len() as u32,
                        p_signal_semaphores: render_semaphores.as_ptr(),
                    },
                ];

                device
                    .queue_submit(present_queue, &submit_info, vk::Fence::null())
                    .unwrap();

                let present_info = vk::PresentInfoKHR {
                    s_type: vk::StructureType::PresentInfoKhr,
                    p_next: ptr::null(),
                    wait_semaphore_count: render_semaphores.len() as u32,
                    p_wait_semaphores: render_semaphores.as_ptr(),
                    swapchain_count: 1,
                    p_swapchains: &swapchain,
                    p_image_indices: &image_index,
                    p_results: ptr::null_mut(),
                };

                swapchain_loader
                    .queue_present_khr(present_queue, &present_info)
                    .unwrap();

                winit::ControlFlow::Continue
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It's possible that some of the values could be deallocated too early, or that I'm passing pointers incorrectly, but I can't see where (I'm relatively new to Rust).

Sorry for the code length, I'm not sure how to simplify this example further. The interesting parts are at the bottom where I submit the pipeline barriers and semaphores. The Vulkan SDK I'm using is 1.0.57.0, ash is 0.18.4, winit is 0.7, kernel32-sys is 0.2.2.

I would appreciate any suggestions to go about debugging this as well. I tried (and will keep trying) stepping into the validation layers to check the individual API calls and compare side-by-side, but it wasn't obvious where the difference is introduced.

Comment: Enable api dump layer, save logs from both applications (C++ and Rust) and compare them. And share them as well. It may be easier to compare directly what Vulkan functions are called and with what parameters than to compare code written in different programming languages.

Comment: @Ekzuzy Sure, I forgot to mention that I already dumped the logs and they look approximately the same (except for addresses). I don't have enough reputation to add them to my question, but they are located here: C++ https://pastebin.com/JyQX8HRa Rust https://pastebin.com/yWJbhPqp

Comment: These api dumps are indeed very similar. But the error code returned by the vkQueueSubmit() function is the VK_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILED_EXT which is reported by the debug report. Maybe the problem is not connected with swapchain images or layout transitions but with the validation / debug report itself? Some time ago someone here on StackOverflow had a problem with his application. It didn't work for him but worked fine on my computer. The only difference was debug report which I disabled during debugging. When he disabled it, application started working for him as well. Did You try that?

Comment: It's a blind shot but I don't have any other ideas what can be potentially wrong. There are some differences in these two api dumps but they shouldn't generate such problems. If it's not the debug report, maybe some specific Rust behavior? I don't know, some additional thread managed internally by Rust environment or, as You wrote, too early deallocation of resources (I don't know Rust at all). I will look at it a bit more but for now I don't have any other ideas about potential problems.

Comment: @Ekzuzy Yes, when I disable the debug layer in the Rust application it appears to work fine, but I can't tell if the pipeline barriers are actually functioning correctly. However the C++ application runs fine on my computer with the debug layer enabled so I'm concerned there is something else going on. I wonder if I have dangling pointers in my API calls or the event loop has some subtle difference.

Comment: Did You try enabling validation layers not in Your code but globally, as described in Vulkan SDK through environment variables and validation layers config file? This way You don't need to modify Your code yet You still should have a validation information printed in the console window. And it shouldn't interfere with Your code.

Comment: @Ekzuzy I've removed the validation layers and I have a layer settings file which includes warnings, but when I do `SET VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS=VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump;VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation && t.exe > debug.txt` the program runs fine with no warnings (even the "additional bits" warning) so I'm not sure the validation layer is being added correctly :-) I will try to look into it

Comment: If api dump layer works correctly, other layers should work as well. I can't say that the code sample doesn't have any bugs, but I tried to test it with validation layers enabled and fixed it until all errors and warnings are gone. ;-)

Comment: Firstly do not return `VK_TRUE` from your debug callback. Secondly layers enabled from command line may require [vk_layer_settings.txt](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/master/layers/vk_layer_settings.txt) to show warnings.

Comment: @Ekzuzy No problem, the tutorials are great! Thanks for writing them and all of your help here.

Comment: @krOoze Very nice catch! The issue seems to have been caused by the `VK_TRUE` in the callback. I had no idea of that restriction, as I copied the callback from an [ash example](https://github.com/MaikKlein/ash/blob/a26f2613fd5fda5cb43384834dbec9e311b0d0ac/examples/src/lib.rs#L132). Thanks. If you want to submit that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @JST It is the cause of `VK_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILED_EXT`. It isn't really the cause of the error/warning messages. PS: the logs have `pNext` set to something while in your code I see you pass `null` which is odd.

Comment: @krOoze But I think `VK_TRUE` explains why the Rust code executes differently than C++, right? That was my main concern.

Interesting, I noticed the C++ logs show `pNext` values as well.

Comment: @JST I does not explain why one has error message and other does not. The logs seem otherwisely identical as far as I can tell. Does that error message disappear from the log with `VK_FALSE` callback? If so that's some kind of a layer bug.

Comment: @krOoze Sorry, yes that's what I meant. The error message doesn't display when I return `VK_FALSE` from the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VK_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILED_EXT` is often returned in the case when you return `VK_TRUE` from your debug callback. [The specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#PFN_vkDebugReportCallbackEXT) advises against doing that:

> The callback returns a `VkBool32` that indicates to the calling layer the application’s desire to abort the call. A value of `VK_TRUE` indicates that the application wants to abort this call. If the application returns `VK_FALSE`, the command **must** not be aborted. Applications **should** always return `VK_FALSE` so that they see the same behavior with and without validation layers enabled.

The value `VK_TRUE` is intended only for the purposes of layer development. Its current use is for unit testing of the layers, which requires the command to be aborted before it reaches the GPU driver (to prevent crashes the test is not interested in). It is common mistake to use it in applications. As the quote says applications are supposed to always use `VK_FALSE`.

In your case the layer is behaving bit oddly, but what probably happened is:

1. Both your app and the tutorial produce a benign warning on `vkCmdPipelineBarrier`.
2. Because you return `VK_TRUE` the barrier is aborted and does not count.
3. `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` returns `void` (i.e. cannot return `VK_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILED_EXT`) so you never learned it was actually aborted.
4. Because the layout transition was aborted you have image in wrong layout on `vkQueueSubmit` and so you get an appropriate error.

Comment: Great summary, this makes sense.